# no dejar reedimensionar ventana

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tengo una página en la que quiero que al darle a un boton, ese boton habra una ventana de Login, con un window.open. Esto lo consigo y todo bien, pero quiero que no se pueda reedimensionar, he visto que hay un atributo llamado resizable, pero que solo para es Internet Explorer .. Existe algun otro metodo para poder hacer eso ?

```js
document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click',()=>{

     window.open("https://es.stackoverflow.com/", "Hola", "width=500,height=500");
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="boton">Abrir ventana</button>
  
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te sirve abrirlo como popup?, creo que a ese te refieres

Comment: Si supongo que es lo mismo. También se podria hacer con CSS? con max height y width?

Comment: No, los tamaños de ventana no son influyentes de ninguna manera, disculpa mi primer comentario creo que lo redacté mal. Te genero de inmediato una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, lamentablemente la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) de **Mozilla Developers** explica explicitamente que no hay ordenes de ese tipo en sus actualizaciones debido a las preferencias de usuario en sus navegadores. Cito un apartado traducido.

> **¿Cómo desactivo la posibilidad de cambiar el tamaño de la ventana o
>   elimino las barras de herramientas?** No puedes forzar esto. Los
>   usuarios con navegadores basados ​​en Mozilla tienen un control
>   absoluto sobre las funcionalidades de la ventana, como la posibilidad
>   de cambiar el tamaño, la capacidad de desplazamiento y la presencia de
>   barras de herramientas a través de las preferencias del usuario
>   about:config. Dado que sus usuarios son los que deben usar tales
>   ventanas (y no usted, como autor web), lo mejor es evitar interferir
>   con sus hábitos y preferencias. Recomendamos establecer siempre la
>   posibilidad de cambiar el tamaño y la presencia de las barras de
>   desplazamiento (si es necesario) en sí para garantizar la
>   accesibilidad al contenido y la usabilidad de las ventanas. Esto es lo
>   mejor para el autor web y los usuarios.

Deberás encontrar otra solución a tu problema o plantearlo de otra forma en una nueva pregunta.

Saludos

**EDIT**

Para la solución a tu problema, puedo decir que puedes ocupar las ventanas modales de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) las cuales te pueden ofrecer una posibilidad como la siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Iniciar Login
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Autenticacion</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="usuario">Usuario</h5>
        <input type="text" />
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="usuario">Password</h5>
        <input type="password" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Autenticar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```